# mySQL where mysql error: [1054: Unknown column 'FULL_NAME' in 'where clause'] in

Tags: mysql, where-clause

```
UPDATE HD_TICKET
set HD_TICKET.CC_LIST =
    case 
    when HD_TICKET.CC_LIST = '' then (SELECT USER.EMAIL, HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE11
FROM USER)
    when HD_TICKET.CC_LIST is null then (SELECT USER.EMAIL, HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE11
FROM USER)
    else  CONCAT(HD_TICKET.CC_LIST, ", ", ((SELECT USER.EMAIL FROM USER))) end
where 
USER.FULL_NAME = HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE11 and (HD_TICKET.ID in (<TICKET_IDS>))
```

I have an update that returns the error Unknown column 'USER.FULL_NAME' in 'where clause'. I have checked the spelling and verified the tables but I cant seem to get around the error. Please help?

Comment: mysql ? or sql-server ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty the 1054 suggests MySQL.

Comment: mysql, I tagged it as that I think. First post so I may of done something wrong.

Comment: The query doesn't really make much sense if there is more than one row in `USER`... or, well, in many ways including trying to squeeze two fields into one in the subqueries. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: It is for a ticket rule for a Dell KACE k1000. basically I want to take a drop down that has a users full name and lookup their email and then place that on the CC_LIST. So I can get that part to work fine but when I start to case statements down it doesnt seem to like that anymore. the "," is needed because it is how the emails are separated in the CC_LIST box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is a bit off... I suspect what you really mean to do is something more like a normal update join;

```
UPDATE HD_TICKET
JOIN USER ON USER.FULL_NAME = HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE11
SET HD_TICKET.CC_LIST =
  CASE WHEN HD_TICKET.CC_LIST = '' OR HD_TICKET.CC_LIST IS NULL THEN USER.EMAIL 
       ELSE CONCAT(HD_TICKET.CC_LIST, ", ", USER.EMAIL)
  END
WHERE HD_TICKET.ID in (<TICKET_IDS>)
```

Comment: I need to add an additional statement to the where clause stating that if the email address is already there do not write it again. I tried to add a not contain USER.EMAIL but it still adds it again.

Comment: @user3634019 Untested, but you should be able to just add something like `AND CONCAT(',',HD_TICKET.CC_LIST,',') NOT LIKE CONCAT('%,',USER.EMAIL,',%')` to the end of the query.

Comment: that does the same thing. it allows the CC-LIST field to be appended to even when the address is already there.

Comment: Btw, just so that it has been mentioned, comma separated fields are seldom a good idea in SQL, you should at least consider breaking the email lists out to a separate table.

Comment: @user3634019 I typo'd the query at first as `LIKE` instead of `NOT LIKE`. Which did you test? Either way, off for a bit now so may not be able to help for a few hours. You may consider asking a new question about that part.

Comment: AND CONCAT(',',HD_TICKET.CC_LIST,',') NOT LIKE CONCAT('%,',USER.EMAIL,',%')

Comment: UPDATE HD_TICKET
JOIN USER ON USER.FULL_NAME = CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE11
SET HD_TICKET.CC_LIST =
  CASE WHEN HD_TICKET.CC_LIST = '' OR HD_TICKET.CC_LIST IS NULL THEN USER.EMAIL 
       ELSE CONCAT(HD_TICKET.CC_LIST, ", ", USER.EMAIL)
  END
WHERE HD_TICKET.ID in (<TICKET_IDS>) AND CONCAT(',',HD_TICKET.CC_LIST,',') NOT LIKE CONCAT('%,',USER.EMAIL,',%')

Answer (score 2):

you need to join the table USER .Try that.

```
UPDATE HD_TICKET 
INNER JOIN USER ON USER.FULL_NAME = HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE11
set HD_TICKET.CC_LIST =
    case 
    when HD_TICKET.CC_LIST = '' 
         then (SELECT USER.EMAIL, HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE11 FROM USER)
    when HD_TICKET.CC_LIST is null 
         then (SELECT USER.EMAIL, HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE11 FROM USER)
    else  CONCAT(HD_TICKET.CC_LIST, ", ", USER.EMAIL) end
 where  HD_TICKET.ID in (<TICKET_IDS>)
```

edit:

in this  `SELECT USER.EMAIL FROM USER` you are selecting many emails . you have to make limit or specify the email by where clause to return one email

```
 else  CONCAT(HD_TICKET.CC_LIST, ", ", ((SELECT USER.EMAIL FROM USER LIMIT 1 )))
```

or use this

```
 GROUP_CONCAT(USER.EMAIL)
```

or this

```
 CONCAT(HD_TICKET.CC_LIST, ", ", USER.EMAIL)
```

Comment: That is a good example how problematic comma joins are. In this case a complete table was missing.

Comment: mysql error: [1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)]

Comment: 05/13/2014 16:07:43> Starting: 05/13/2014 16:07:43
05/13/2014 16:07:43> Executing Select Query...
05/13/2014 16:07:43> selected 6 rows
05/13/2014 16:07:43> Executing Update Query...
05/13/2014 16:07:43> mysql error: [1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)] in EXECUTE("UPDATE HD_TICKET 
INNER JOIN USER ON USER.FULL_NAME = HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE11
set HD_TICKET.CC_LIST =
    case

Comment: try this instead `CONCAT(HD_TICKET.CC_LIST, ", ", USER.EMAIL)`